# Can I use smart contracts on the Hedera network?

Tags: smartcontracts, hashgraph, hedera-hashgraph

Does the Hedera Hashgraph Network support smart contracts, and is it possible to migrate smart contracts to Hedera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart contracts are supported. See the documentation [here](https://docs.hedera.com/guides/docs/sdks/smart-contracts/create-a-smart-contract).

In addition, Smart Contracts 2.0 were announced and will be introduced around 21Q4 - see the [Hedera roadmap](https://hedera.com/roadmap) and the [announcement](https://hedera.com/blog/hedera-evm-smart-contracts-now-bring-highest-speed-programmability-to-tokenization) for more details.
In short, Smart Contracts 2.0 will enable running hundreds of Solidity smart contracts per second. This will also facilitate migration from other networks while minimizing code changes.

```
//Create the transaction const transaction = new ContractCreateTransaction()
    .setGas(500)
    .setBytecodeFileId(bytecodeFileId)
    .setAdminKey(adminKey);

//Modify the default max transaction fee (1 hbar) const modifyTransactionFee = transaction.setMaxTransactionFee(new Hbar(16));

//Sign the transaction with the client operator key and submit to a Hedera network const txResponse = await modifyTransactionFee.execute(client)
```